# MediaPlayer failed to play audio bytes via socket-io server

Tags: java, android, socket.io

**Context:**

- I have two devices running the same android app.
- The app starts a recorder `onCreate`.
- The recorded bytes are sent to a node socket server.
- The socket server sends the audio to the other device, where the socket event listener sets up the media player to play the audio.
- Media player fails at the `mediaPlayer.prepare()` method.

I also have used a `MediaDataSource` class to store the bytes.

```
// MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "socket_main_act";
    private static final int REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION = 200;
    private static final int SAMPLING_RATE = 22050;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    private MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    private boolean permissionToRecord = false;
    private String [] permissions = {Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO};

    private void startRecording(Socket socket) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "start recording.");
        try {
            ParcelFileDescriptor[] descriptors = ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe();
            ParcelFileDescriptor recorderRead = new ParcelFileDescriptor(descriptors[0]);
            ParcelFileDescriptor recorderWrite = new ParcelFileDescriptor(descriptors[1]);
            InputStream inputStream = new ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseInputStream(recorderRead);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Setup IO.");

            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AAC_ADTS);
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC_ELD);
            recorder.setOutputFile(recorderWrite.getFileDescriptor());
            recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(SAMPLING_RATE);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Setup recorder.");
            recorder.prepare();
            recorder.start();
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Start recording.");

            int read = 1;
            byte[] data = new byte[SAMPLING_RATE];

            while (read != -1) {
                read = inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length);
                socket.emit("audio", (Object) data);
            }
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Data from recorder exhausted.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Recording faults");
        }
    }

    public Emitter.Listener onAudioBroadcast = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream os;
            byte[] data;
            try {
                os = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
                for (Object arg : args) {
                    os.writeObject(arg);
                }
                data = out.toByteArray();
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Read data as byte array.");
                AudioDataSource src = new AudioDataSource(data);
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Setup player and src");
                AudioAttributes attr = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setFlags(AudioAttributes.FLAG_AUDIBILITY_ENFORCED)
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
                    .build();
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Setup attributes");
                mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(attr);
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Player set with attributes.");
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(src);
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Player read from source");
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "prepare player.");
                mediaPlayer.start();
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Start playing.");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Player failed to stream audio: " + e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION:
                permissionToRecord = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                break;
        }
        if (!permissionToRecord) finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            Socket mSocket = IO.socket("http://192.168.2.49:3000");
            mSocket.on("audio-broadcast", onAudioBroadcast);
            mSocket.connect();
            startRecording(mSocket);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "uri is invalid.");
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the `MediaDataSource` implementation.

```
public class AudioDataSource extends MediaDataSource {

    private byte[] data;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "audio_src";

    public AudioDataSource(byte[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int readAt(long position, byte[] buffer, int offset, int size) throws IOException {
        if (position >= data.length) return -1;
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Data non-empty.");
        int endPosition = (int)(position + size);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, String.valueOf(endPosition));
        int adjustedSize = size;
        if (endPosition > data.length) {
            adjustedSize -= endPosition - data.length;
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, String.valueOf(adjustedSize));
        }
        System.arraycopy(data, (int)position, buffer, offset, adjustedSize);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Copy array");
        return adjustedSize;
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize() throws IOException {
        return (long)data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException { }
}
```

The logs here show that there is some data moving around, yet the error:

```
I/audio_src: Data non-empty.
2019-12-30 22:24:59.154 17285-17919/com.example.socket_client_demo I/audio_src: 22528
2019-12-30 22:24:59.154 17285-17919/com.example.socket_client_demo I/audio_src: 1597
2019-12-30 22:24:59.154 17285-17919/com.example.socket_client_demo I/audio_src: Copy array
2019-12-30 22:24:59.154 17285-17919/com.example.socket_client_demo I/audio_src: Data non-empty.
2019-12-30 22:24:59.155 17285-17919/com.example.socket_client_demo I/audio_src: 2048
2019-12-30 22:24:59.155 17285-17919/com.example.socket_client_demo I/audio_src: Copy array
2019-12-30 22:24:59.156 17285-17919/com.example.socket_client_demo E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)
2019-12-30 22:24:59.156 17285-17349/com.example.socket_client_demo E/socket_main_act: Player failed to stream audio: java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
```

I am assuming that `mediaPlayer` is not able to process the data from the `src`? Please help me find what is incorrect with my approach.

If it would help to run the app on your system, [here](https://github.com/ltbringer/socket_client_demo) is the repo for the same. You would need a socket.io server too, make sure the phone is connected to the same network as your socket server.

Comment: Have you configured `networkSecurityConfig` in your Manifest?

Comment: Pardon me for I don't know why I'd need that, could you tell me what is the use for it?

Comment: No worries. It's because that same IO exception occurs (for media player) when you don't have network security configured in your manifest. See this post for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55479574/android-mediaplayer-java-io-ioexception-prepare-failed-status-0x1